# Nordic characters in matlab code

Tags: unicode, matlab

I'm new here and pretty new to LaTeX, so go easy on me. I'm importing MATLAB code from .m files using \lstset{language=Matlab}, but have some trouble with nordic characters "å, ä, ö". the rest of the report is written in swedish and looks great, but the MATLAB code is giving me this error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\expandafter\lst@FillFixed@ (U+A99)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 ...         %index f�r vilken k�rning vi �r p�

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

The easiest way would be to edit the comments in the program or copy the code and edit it in LaTeX, but I want to understand the error and try to fix it and get better att LaTeX. 
I've tried

```
\lstset{language=Matlab,
    literate= {ö}{{\"o}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {ä}{{\"a}}1 {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1 
}
```

but with no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal example of code producing the error? Starting from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Comment: Are you sure that the matlab .m files are encoded in UTF-8? U+A99 is this: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0A99/index.htm